# Empty ArrayList equals null

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is an empty Arraylist (with nulls as its items) be considered as null? So, essentially would the below statement be true:

```
if (arrayList != null)
```

thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No.

An ArrayList can be empty (or with nulls as items) an not be null. It would be considered empty. You can check for am empty ArrayList with:

```
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
if(arrList.isEmpty())
{
    // Do something with the empty list here.
}
```

Or if you want to create a method that checks for an ArrayList with only nulls:

```
public static Boolean ContainsAllNulls(ArrayList arrList)
{
    if(arrList != null)
    {
        for(object a : arrList)
            if(a != null) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not return boolean (primitive type) instead of Boolean (object)?

Comment: can you give me an example as how to create an empty arrayList?

Answer (score 23):

`arrayList == null` if there are no instance of the class `ArrayList` assigned to the variable `arrayList` (note the upercase for classes and the lowercase for variables).

If, at anytime, you do `arrayList = new ArrayList()` then `arrayList != null` because is pointing to an instance of the class `ArrayList`

If you want to know if the list is empty, do

```
if(arrayList != null && !arrayList.isEmpty()) {
 //has items here. The fact that has items does not mean that the items are != null. 
 //You have to check the nullity for every item

}
else {
// either there is no instance of ArrayList in arrayList or the list is empty.
}
```

If you don't want null items in your list, I'd suggest you to extend the ArrayList class with your own, for example:

```
public class NotNullArrayList extends ArrayList{

@Override
public boolean add(Object o) 
   { if(o==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add null items to the list");
      else return super.add(o);
    }
}
```

Or maybe you can extend it to have a method inside your own class that re-defines the concept of "empty List".

```
public class NullIsEmptyArrayList extends ArrayList{

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() 
   if(super.isEmpty()) return true;
   else{
   //Iterate through the items to see if all of them are null. 
   //You can use any of the algorithms in the other responses. Return true if all are null, false otherwise. 
   //You can short-circuit to return false when you find the first item not null, so it will improve performance.
  }
}
```

The last two approaches are more Object-Oriented, more elegant and reusable solutions.

**Updated** with Jeff suggestion IAE instead of NPE.

Comment: Nice suggestions!  I would use an IllegalArgumentException rather than a NPE in the NotNullArrayList example.

Answer (score 5):

No, this will not work.  The best you will be able to do is to iterate through all values and check them yourself:

```
boolean empty = true;
for (Object item : arrayList) {
    if (item != null) {
        empty = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which would return false for a list containing a single null value, so maybe not.

Comment: @Mark thanks, fixed.  Seems that the title 'Empty ArrayList equals null' threw me.

Answer (score 2):

Just as zero is a number - just a number that represents none - an empty list is still a list, just a list with nothing in it.  `null` is no list at all; it's therefore different from an empty list.

Similarly, a list that contains null items is a list, and is *not* an empty list.  Because it has items in it; it doesn't matter that those items are themselves null.  As an example, a list with three null values in it, and nothing else: what is its length?  Its length is 3.  The empty list's length is zero.  And, of course, null doesn't have a length.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it contains items there must be an instance of it. Its items being null is irrelevant, so the statment ((arrayList) != null) == true

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can verify this on your own by writing a simple TestCase!

> empty Arraylist (with nulls as its items)

Second, If ArrayList is EMPTY that means it is **really empty**, it cannot have NULL or NON-NULL things as element.

Third,

```
 List list  = new ArrayList();
    list.add(null);
    System.out.println(list == null)
```

would print false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the array contains items with null values, use this:

```
private boolean isListOfNulls(ArrayList<String> stringList){
    for (String s: stringList)
        if( s != null) return false;
    return true;
}
```

You could replace `<String>` with the corresponding type for your `ArrayList`